# Log4j2 : RollingFile appender does not write logs into file

Tags: java, log4j2

My `log4j2.xml` is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="R"/>
        </Async>

        <RollingFile name="R" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/myServer.log" filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/myServer.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>      
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>        
        <Logger name="com.ps" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
        </Logger>       

        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This configuration only creates myServer.log file and does not roll file also does not write logs into it.

Log file is created with permissions :

```
ls -ltr my*
-rw-------. 1 root root      0 Feb 14 18:15 myServer.log
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should add reference to your Rolling file Appender to  get logs written in your File.

```
<Root level="WARN">
    <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="R"/>
 </Root>
```

More information on configuring log4j2 can be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<AppenderRef ref="R"/>` as well under `<Root level="WARN">` tag and try again.